# Eager Execution: Could not find valid device for node. {{node Conv2D}}

Tags: python, tensorflow, eager-execution

I'm trying to build a image classifier in Tensorflow under the eager-execution mode. I am receiving the following error.

```
InternalError: Could not find valid device for node.
Node: {{node Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_UINT8, data_format="NHWC", 
dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], 
use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](dummy_input, dummy_input)
All kernels registered for op Conv2D :
device='XLA_CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_HALF]
device='XLA_GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_BFLOAT16, 
DT_HALF]
device='GPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
device='XLA_CPU_JIT'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_HALF]
device='XLA_GPU_JIT'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_BFLOAT16, 
DT_HALF]
[Op:Conv2D]
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: I have the same problem, and my input tensor is float32

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you are trying to load an int32 tensor to the conv2d block. You will have to check the supported input tensor types before passing a tensor to a particular tensorflow function.

For instance if you checkout the tensorflow source code over here [tf.nn.conv2d](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6612da89516247503f03ef76e974b51a434fb52e/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L1410) for conv2d, the supported input types are `half`, `bfloat16`, `float32`, `float64`.

This is also indicated in your error after the statement - "All kernels registered for op Conv2D"